# Inserts conflict with the foreign key constraint but it is inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to insert a row in a SQL Server 2005 database and I'm getting a foreign key constraint violations.

When I look in the database I see the record that I was trying to insert (and is in conflict with the FK). I was under the impression that records that fail a FK are not inserted.

Is there a way that this could happen?

Regards,
Bas Hendriks.

Comment: I dont think its possible. You may be getting this message due to an subsequent action caused by the insert (like a trigger for example)
Post the structure of your tables so we can analyze

Comment: I agree.  Are you certain that the record present is the one being inserted?  And are you certain that the FK Violation relates to that record?  Have you checked that the PK the FK refers to definately doesn't exist?  If the record successfully inserted, I'd bet the related PK exists, and this would indicate the FK violation is related to something else.  (A trigger, or some other business logic being fired?)

Comment: Are you sure that the "Enforce Foreign Key Constraint" property is set to "Yes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the DBA'er of this particular database has set the `Enforce Foreign Key Constraint` property to "No". It's beyond me why.

Thanks for the hint Lamak!